# Switching the Style depending on the language in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, right-to-left

I want to change the style depends on the language. For example, when I switch the site language to Arabic I want the rtl style that I wrote to take effect and to unset the rtl style when switching back to English. How to achieve that in Drupal 7?
I tried this [answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/68945/how-to-have-different-style-files-in-multilingual-website-using-drupal) but didn't work for me.

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/theming/working-with-css/supporting-right-to-left-rtl-languages & https://www.drupal.org/node/3696

Comment: https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-css-lang

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to use language class Drupal is adding to body element. Check your page html and see what classes body tag has. There should be some class similar to "i18n-de" (in this case for German). Then you can use it to style differently any element inside body tag (basically all of them), like:

```
body.i18n-de div#header {.some css.}
body.i18n-en div#header {.some other css.}
```